# For $x, y, z \in R^n$, show if $x \cdot y = z \cdot y$ , $x = z$

Tags: vectors, solution-verification, inner-products, cross-product

Is it right for me to do the following?

$x \cdot y = z \cdot y$

$x \cdot y - z \cdot y =0$

$(x-z) \cdot y= 0$

Let y = (x-z)

$(x-z) \cdot (x-z) = 0$

x = z

Similarly for another question, For $x, y, z$ in $R^3,$ show if  $ x \times y = z \times y$ , $x = z$, how do I begin proving this question

Comment: The first claim is false when $n\ge1$ (or when $z=0$)

Comment: You don't even have to let $y=x-z$; if $(x-z)\cdot y=0$, and $y$ is not zero in general, then $x=z$.

Comment: We have
$$xy = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \ \ \text{ and }\ \ 
zy = \sum_{i=1}^n z_iy_i$$
From the condition, $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i = \sum_{i=1}^n z_iy_i \implies \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - z_i)y_i = 0$$
I don't see why $x_i = z_i$ must hold.

Comment: A nice illustration that quantifiers are important.

Comment: A special case would be if for **all** $\,x\,$ **then** (if for **all** $\,y\,$ we have $\,x\cdot y = 0\,$ then $\,x=0)\,$.Note the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

*If* the question is:

> If $x,z\in\Bbb R^n$ are such that $(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n):x.y=z.y$, then $x=z$.

then your answer is correct.

In the case of the cross-product, it's a little different. Assuming this time that the question is:

> If $x,z\in\Bbb R^n$ are such that $(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n):x\times y=z\times y$, then $x=z$.

this can be done as follows: if $x\ne z$ take a vector $y\ne0$ which is orthogonal to $x-y$. Then $\|(x-z)\times y\|=\|x-z\|.\|y\|\ne0$, and therefore $(x-z)\times y\ne0$. It follows that $x\times y\ne z\times y$.

Comment: Hi, for the cross product is it prove by contrapositive? By showing ~q-> ~p it proves p-> q? I do not quite get the part ∥x−y∥.∥y∥≠0 Have edited qn on cross product to make it clearer

Comment: Yes, it is a proved by contradiction. I proved that if $x\ne z$, then there is a vector $y$ such that $x\times y\ne z\times y$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your swift reply, I still do not understand how ∥(x−z)×y∥ is derived and equates ∥x−y∥.∥y∥, After I take y is orthogonal to x-y how can the derive the above? Apologies in advance for my ignorance, am currently new in calculus

Comment: If $v,w\in\Bbb R^3$ and if $\theta$ is the angle between them, then $\|v\times w\|=\|v\|.\|w\|\sin(\theta)$. So, if $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal we have $\|v\times w\|=\|v\|.\|w\|$.

Comment: I see but ∥x−y∥.∥y∥ will be be equal to ∥(x−y)×y∥ not ∥(x−z)×y∥ right?

Comment: Sure. That was a typo. I've edited my answer.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

$$a\cdot x=0$$ is true for all $x$ perpendicular to $a$. In 2D, this is a straight line and in 3D a plane.

$$a\times x=0$$ is true for all $x$ parallel to $a$, which is a straight line in 3D.

So $x=0$ is not necessarily true.